# Subgraph isomorphism index/precomputation

Tags: matching, graph-isomorphism

I'm currently working on problem in which a set of graphs $T=\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}$ is given and fixed.
Given a graph $m$ I want to check which of the $t_i$ are subgraphs of it, as quick as possible.
Is there any way to organize the graphs in $T$ beforehand to speed up this procedure?

I found that using a [substructure screen](https://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.finger.html) helps, but I'm looking for further improvements.

Comment: These graphs are undirected. I already looked into the literature a bit but I haven't even found sources where the subgraph queries are fixed.
Seems like a very untypical problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem#Applications